# need to do an ascii shift cypher in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to shift the characters in a string by 20 to match a file format I used in basic. I am using the following code in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test_controls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string text3;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This is a test conversion of my pdw save routine from   basic to c#
        int pos = 0;
        string text = label1.Text;
        int t = text.Length;     // get the length of the text
        while (pos < t + 1) ;
        string s = text.Substring(pos, 1); // get subsstring 1 character at a time

        byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text); // convert that character to ascii
        foreach (byte b in ASCIIValues)
        {
            int temp = b;
            temp = temp + 20;   // add 20 to the ascii value
            char text2 = Convert.ToChar(temp); // convert the acii back into a char
            text3 =""+ text2.ToString(); // add the char to the final string

        }
        label1.Text = text3; // rewrite the new string to replace the old one for the label1.text
    }

}
```

}

The problem is it just does nothing and doesn't respond and I have to tell windows to close the unresponsive program. To be clear, I'm using winforms in c# to make a shift cypher. All of this code I'm using I found in various answers and pieced it together. in Vb or any other basic, I would just get the ascii value of each character in the string then do the math and convert it back using the chr$ command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `while (pos < t + 1) ;` is necessarily an infinite loop...

Comment: It's incorrect to do "temp = temp + 20" as it will result in many of your letters no longer being letters. If you're doing a shift of 2, for example, you want "z" to map to "b," which will entail subtraction (not addition). In this example, note that z = 122 and 122 + 20 = 142, which isn't even a valid ASCII character anymore.

Comment: I just want to get the value back into a character and back into a string regardless of the character it becomes. In my file format, because of the plus 20, the space even becomes a different character thus the resulting string having no spaces. Then, I reverse the process as needed so it will save and load in an encrypted format. I wondered if it wasn't an infinite loop myself at one point. Only reason I coded it that way is because in basic I used a for next loop so I thought the while would process until the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, but this entails you trying to display something that isn't even valid ASCII on the string. As a third error, you're not actually appending the new character values to the string - you're replacing the string with the most recent character every iteration.

Comment: Ok I understand so what I will do is I will have the Word processor store the filename in a file using streamwriter, then use the process start command to call up the two respective code an decode routines I already have exe files for in Liberty Basic. This will encode before the rtf save and decode before the rtfload. All the user will see is the normal document. This way  it can't be viewed without the proper program. It is the same thing msword does only different. It's a proprietary save format.

Comment: This trip through text-land is fraught with hazards. Just do what encryption algorithms do: block of bytes in, block of bytes out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. As pointed out in the comments, the following line is an infinite loop:

```
while (pos < t + 1) ;
```

Even without the loop, though, your shift algorithm is incorrect. The following line will also lead to incorrect results:

```
temp = temp + 20;
```

Consider as counterexamples the following cases:

- G maps to [
- ASCII z = 122. 122 + 20 = 144, which isn't even a valid ASCII character.
- Uppercase Z would map to lowercase *n*
  You could come up with other similar cases.

Incidentally, you could also rewrite this line as `temp += 20`.

Finally, this line is incorrect:

```
text3 =""+ text2.ToString();
```

You're not appending the new text to text3, you're replacing it every time you do an iteration, so text3 will always contain the last character encoded (rather  than the entire string). Keep in mind, too, that building a C# string like this (especially a long one) is inefficient as strings are immutable objects in C#. If the string in question might be long you want to consider using a StringBuilder for this purpose.